# Firebase Realtime Database - Multi Group Access?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I currently have a database structure resembling the following. Without the ability to loop inside Firebase Realtime Database secutiry rules, how can I secure data based on a users access to multiple groups? Example to follow...

**The database structure:**

```
// list of different groups a user can belong to.
// they can belong to multiple groups.

"userGroups": {
  "groupA": ...
  "groupB": ...
  "groupC": ...
}

// each user has a list of group ids they belong to

"users": {
  "userA": {
    groups: ['groupA', 'groupB'],
  },
  "userB": {
    groups: ['groupB'],
  }
}

// various nodes in the database an admin sets restriction on content
// so specific data can only be access by specified group

"someFunData": {
  "data1": {
    authorisedGroups: ['groupA', 'groupB'],
  },
  "data2": {
    authorisedGroups: ['groupB'],
  }
}
```

How can I specify security rules on `someFunData` to restrict it based on a match between any group specified in `someFunData/$dataId/authorisedGroups` to the current user's `groups`?

Answer (score 0):

First, `userGroups` can be misleading. It could mean "the groups of each user". If you don't have any other kinds of groups, you can call it just `groups`.

In a similar scenario, I created a Cloud Function for every path that affects what a user should see.

```
const updateUserFunData = (path: string) => {
    return functions.database.ref(path).onWrite(async (data, context) => {
        // Download any required data, calculate what changes should be made,
        // then use a multi-path update to save these changes, like this:
        await rootRef.child('userFunData').update({
            [uid1 + '/' + data1]: true, // or a complete copy of the data
            [uid1 + '/' + data2]: null, // use null to delete
        });
    });
};
export const onUserGroupsChange = updateUserFunData('users/{uid}/groups');
export const onFunDataGroupsChange = updateUserFunData('someFunData/{dataId}/groups');
```

Then clients can read `userFunData/$uid` to get their data IDs (and then get each `funData`), and rules can check if `userFunData/$uid/$dataId` exists, to allow or deny a read.

If you want to skip that intermediate funData IDs query and the synchronization of all the following queries, you can replace `true` with a full copy of the data, add a trigger for the other db changes that should change that data, and have clients query only `userFunData/$uid`, which should contain all the data they should see.

---

You commented that maintaining a per-user list of data would not be practical. You can maintain a per-group list of data, and have each user get the data of each of their groups. The rules would check if the user exists in the users of the group being read. You would have to save the users of each group (or the groups of each user) as a map instead of an array.

Comment: I don't think in my case it's realistic to store a list of accessible data ids on each user. Access is not fixed/preset as it can be changed by the creator anytime. Meaning potentially tens of thousands of writes would be required if any user updated any access to their data.